# Ajax request error with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I simple make get req with ajax to elasticsearc to get all indices,
in browser it works here:
[image]

its same in my ajax, I expected the json data in browser return to my success method but failed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Response is not JSON**, 
you can change the response to a JSON in your server program.

Comment: I see but actually it was because of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I install a plugin that's fine now.

Comment: You means your ajax's host is different from the data provider,
in that case, you need `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` to cross-host.
Very well.

Comment: my development platform is .net mvc. (if it is your porint) yes its. But I did not understand whats problem with that. I simply make a request from ajax whats wrong with .net _?

Comment: I mean the ajax page url is `http://www.test.local/../...`,
but the data provider is `http://localhost:9200/_cat/...`,

in this case, your ajax request need to cross-host, just what you do with `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`
if your two page are both the same host like:`http://www.abc.local/../...`
ajax request did not need to cross-host

Comment: But my both ajax host(http://localhost:55421/Builder/Index) and data provider(localhost:9200) in same host(localhost). Just ports are diffirent..why it ask for access cross host ? because of ports or ?

Comment: cross-domain happened when protocols, domain names or ports are different between the request and server.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you replace `json` by `jsonp` in your dataType parameter, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9200/dicoms/dicoms/_search",
    dataType: "jsonp",              <--- change this
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: it was because of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I install a plugin now it works but wonder what's that mean